# How to render SVG image to single-color bitmap image?

Tags: c#, .net, svg, bitmap

Using the [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) NuGet package to render SVG images to bitmap images in .NET, I'm trying to change the color of the image during rendering.

E.g. I have this source SVG image:

[image]

and want to render it e.g. as a green bitmap image:

[image]

(In my scenario, all source SVG images are single-colored only).

My current, *unsuccessful* code looks like this:

```cs
var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(svgFilePath, null);

// Tried several things, all without any changes in the resulting bitmap:
svgDoc.Color = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.StopColor = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);

var bitmap = svgDoc.Draw();
```

I've also checked-out the source code and looked through it, but I still found no way to change the color.

**My question:**

How to change the color during rendering an SVG image to a bitmap image with SVG.NET?

*(I'm asking here on SO and not only on their GitHub page, since it seems that the authors do not respond to [questions](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/issues) at all or very seldom only)*

**Update 1:**

What did work is the following fragment:

```cs
var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(svgFilePath, null);

// Recursively change all nodes.
processNodes(svgDoc.Descendants(), new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen));

var bitmap = svgDoc.Draw();
```

together with this function:

```cs
private void processNodes(
    IEnumerable<SvgElement> nodes, SvgPaintServer colorServer)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Fill != SvgPaintServer.None) node.Fill = colorServer;
        if (node.Color != SvgPaintServer.None) node.Color = colorServer;
        if (node.StopColor != SvgPaintServer.None) node.StopColor = colorServer;
        if (node.Stroke != SvgPaintServer.None) node.Stroke = colorServer;

        processNodes(node.Descendants(), colorServer);
    }
}
```

Although I am unsure about the costs of this recursive iteration of all nodes and whether there is a faster way.

Comment: What things have you tried?
Have you tried adding a color to the fill init?

Comment: My source code in the question shows, what I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds reasonable that your first attempt failed, because you only set `fill` and `stroke` on the parent `<svg>` element, and a parent's fill/stroke doesn't override a child's fill/stroke. Example:

```html
<svg fill="green" stroke="green" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" >
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" >
        <path d="M90,90 v-80 a80,80 0 0,0 -80,80 z" fill="red" />
        <path d="M100,100 h-80 a80,80 0 1,0 80,-80 z" fill="gold" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

One alternative to your updated approach is to set fill/stroke via CSS, because CSS will override any `fill` and `stroke` attributes. So, if **SVG.NET** allows you to insert/edit a `<style>` element in your SVG, you can do this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" >
    <style>
        * {
            fill: green;
            stroke: green;
        }
    </style>
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" >
        <path d="M90,90 v-80 a80,80 0 0,0 -80,80 z" fill="red" />
        <path d="M100,100 h-80 a80,80 0 1,0 80,-80 z" fill="gold" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Does SVG.NET support CSS? It seems, but I'm not quite sure. Thanks for your answer, I'll try to dig further into tjhis direction.